# GIT Branching and checkout

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging, git-checkout

I have GIT setup for my website, wherein i have 3 branches (development, staging, master). Development has already some changes ahead from staging and master, now there was an urgent requirement for a bug fix.

I checked out a separate branch from development, and committed changes for the urgent fix in it

Now when i try to merge this new branch into staging, it shows me all prior changes too, instead of the showing changes which i just now committed to this branch.

Can anyone tell me how shall i create a branch which does not show other development branch changes while merging to staging.

Comment: What are `"all prior changes"` ?  Can you have a closer look at some of the merge conflicts and then report to us what you think is happening?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new branch, it will have all the changes of your checked out branch. In your case say you are in `Dev` branch and you create new `UrgentChanges` branch & checkout it will contain all content of `Dev` branch. Now if you merge `UrgentChanges` to `staging` it is going to have dev work + urgent work (from the `UrgentChanges` branch) merged into  staging.

What you should have done is to first checkout to `staging` before you created `UrgentChanges` branch. This way when you merge `UrgentChanges` to `staging` it is going to have original staging work + urgent work.

[Click to read more](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging)

Answer (score 0):

As Prashanth states, you want to create the new branch while you have the one you want to deviate from checked out -- in this case you said you wanted to modify staging's branch.

But we all make these mistakes from time to time, which is one of the reasons git is so great -- all is not lost! Make sure all your changes are committed to your urgent fix branch, and note from git log the sha of the commits you want applied to the staging branch.

Now checkout your staging branch, and for safety create a new urgent2 branch. Armed with the shas you noted earlier, you can cherry pick them over to urgent2.

There are lots of good tutorials on cherry picking. Here is one: http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/rebase-from-the-ground-up/cherry-picking-explained.html

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, if you do not want development branch changes to be there in your urgent bug fix branch, instead of checking out from the development branch you should checkout from the staging branch. Follow the below steps

If you are in your current development branch, make sure you commit all your changes, and the switch to the staging branch first

```
git checkout staging
```

Once in staging branch, you can then checkout a new branch for the bug fix as below

```
git checkout -b urgentfixbranch
```

Verify you are now in the urgentfixbranch (checked out from staging) by using git branch command

```
git branch
```

which shows something like

```
* urgentfixbranch
  staging
  master
  development
```

* indicates your current branch

Next you can make all the code changes and fixes you need to this branch and make sure you commit it to the branch. Once all the changes are done, you can then merge these changes to the staging branch as follows

```
git checkout staging
git merge urgentfixbranch
```

This will merge your urgent fix code changes to the staging and since you created this branch from staging itself and not development, you will not have other development changes in your staging now. You can then delete the urgentfixbranch after you have merged the changes to staging.

```
git branch -d urgentfixbranch
```

Hope this helps!